# create new column pandas as grouped column

Tags: python, pandas

how should i do to create new column in my dataframe named turnover2.

what is fault in what im writing please?

Thank you,

```
df['turnover2'] = df.groupby(['id', 'date'])['turnover'].agg('sum')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the neat `transform` function:

```py
df['turnover2'] = df.groupby(['id', 'date'])['turnover'].transform(sum)
```